# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $ Error in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting this error in my Kotlin Project, I could not find the solution anywhere.

Error ;

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

**My ApiService ;**

```
 @GET("/api/Demak/GetDemakBarcodeOlustur?")
    suspend fun getDemakBarcodes(
        @Query("api") api: String,
        @Query("islem") islem: String,
        @Query("malkod") malkod : String,
        @Query("birim") birim: String,
        @Query("barcodefield") barcodefield: String,
        @Query("barcodevalue") barcodevalue:String
    ): Response<List<DemakBarcodes>>
```

**My Model ;**

```
data class DemakBarcodes(
    val BARKOD1:String,
    val BARKOD2:String,
    val BARKOD3:String,
    val BARKOD4:String,
    val BARKOD5:String,
)
```

**My Page (gives error in there)**

```
    private fun updateBarcode(buttonName:String,editText:TextInputEditText,barcodeText:String){
        viewModel.getDataDemakBarcodes(apiUrl,"DEGISTIR",malkod,birimKod,buttonName,barcodeText)
        viewModel.dataLoading.observeProgress(viewLifecycleOwner,binding.pgBar)
        viewModel.liveDataDemakBarcodes.myObserve(
            viewLifecycleOwner,
            success = {
                println("succesa girdi")
                if(buttonName=="BARCODE1"){ editText.setText(it[0].BARKOD1) }
                if(buttonName=="BARCODE2"){ editText.setText(it[0].BARKOD2) }
                if(buttonName=="BARCODE3"){ editText.setText(it[0].BARKOD3) }
                if(buttonName=="BARCODE4"){ editText.setText(it[0].BARKOD4) }
                if(buttonName=="BARCODE5"){ editText.setText(it[0].BARKOD5) }
                toastSuccess(str(R.string.barkod_guncellendi))
            },

            empty = {
                    toastWarning("Boş Veri")
            },

            error = {
                println("error : error")
                showErrorDialog(
                    title = it,
                    confirm={

                    },
                    buttonPositiveText = str(R.string.tamam),
                )
            }
        )
    }
```

**My ViewModel ;**

```
    fun getDataDemakBarcodes(apiUrl: String,islem:String,malKod:String,birim:String,barcodefield:String,barcodevalue:String): SingleLiveEvent<NetworkResult<List<DemakBarcodes>>> {
        dataLoading.value = true
        viewModelScope.launch {
            api.getDemakBarcodes(apiUrl,islem,malKod,birim,barcodefield,barcodevalue)
                .getData(dataLoading) {
                    liveDataDemakBarcodes.value = it
                }
        }
        return liveDataDemakBarcodes
    }
```

I added @Serialized to the model, but I could not find a solution. Additionally, the stored procedure on the SQL side works without any problems.

Comment: The error means your response starts with an `{` and not an `[`. In other words, it's a single object and not a list

Comment: @Ivo I was thinking the same thing, so what steps should I try as a solution?

Comment: just look at what the api actually returns

Comment: https://prnt.sc/I1I36ca9k-Ly I tested the data returned in Postman and it returns like this.

Comment: Strange, in that case I wouldn't expect that error. I have no idea how to help you then

Answer (score 0):

Your model is **expecting a array or list but it gets json object.**

So it can not convert into model.

So check your api in postman or print it in logcat.

Then check each fields. If you found out the issue

1. Change the model depends on the api.
2. If it's not possible change the api response.(backend)

Comment: How  can i print api in logcat?

Comment: I mean api response. When the api response is successfull print the response.body in Log

Comment: https://prnt.sc/I1I36ca9k-Ly  

I tested the data returned in Postman and it returns like this.